# JPAQL (Hibernate expecting IDENT)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Whats wrong with the following JPA query

select count(obj) from User as obj join obj.directoryNumbers as directoryNumbers where ((upper(obj.userId) like :userId58460273) and ((directoryNumbers in :1011355684)))

executing it gives me this error:
expecting IDENT, found '1011355684'

this parameter (:1011355684) is a list of DirectoryNumber objects, obj.directoryNumbers is a collection of DirectoryNumber objects. User and DirectoryNumber have OneToMany relation.

I'm using Hibernate 3.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you rename the second parameter '1011355684'? It might be that hibernate expects a literal there, not a number.

Comment: thanks for your replay, but this query is generated I have no control over the param name, besides hibernate doesn't seem to have a problem with the same form of parameters in other queries.

Comment: OK, please attach the query to the question. How do you pass the query parameters?

Comment: Well it turns out that you were right its generated incorrectly and hibernate wants the parameter to start with a letter!! I fixed it and now that part works. but still I have a problem, since the parameter is a collection hibernate has transformed the query into :
select count(obj) from com.colurew
are.billing.domain.User as obj join obj.directoryNumbers as directoryNumbers where ((directoryNumbers in :p18881205660_,
 :p18881205661_))

and now it throws the following error :
unexpected AST node: {vector}

Comment: the query is :
select count(obj) from User as obj join obj.directoryNumbers as directoryNumbers where ((directoryNumbers in :p1011355684)))

and the parameter is set like this:

q = em.createQuery(theStringAbove)
query.setParameter(":p1011355684", arrayListOfDirectories);

Comment: got it, it should be using setParameterList.